# Windows 7 process scheduler and Windows Embedded scheduler

Tags: windows-7, windows-embedded

What are the differences in the Windows 7 scheduler and [Windows Embedded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/default.aspx) scheduler ? I last used Windows CE 5.0 (and XP Embedded). As mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded) : "Microsoft has announced that the next version, Windows Embedded Standard 2011, will be based on Windows 7". What components are based on Windows 7, because it also mentions that Windows Embedded Standard is the fully componentized version of Windows XP Professional . There a lot of difference in Windows Xp and Windows 7.
I like the the User Mode Scheduler (in  Windows 7) ,which provides a new model for high-performance applications to control the execution of threads by allowing applications to schedule, throttle and control the overhead due to blocking system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Embedded Standard 2009 (actual available version) is based on XP Pro binaries.

Windows Embedded Standard 7 (previously known as Windows Embedded Standard 2011, and that will be available real soon) is based on Windows 7 binaries.

Basically, what Windows Embedded Standard is is a componentized version of the Desktop OS with the addition of some features specific to Embedded scenarios to enable fast boot, boot from removable media, shell customization,...
for Windows Embedded Standard 7, the binaries are stricly the same as Windows 7 ones, so when it comes to the scheduler, it is exactly the same as the one of the desktop version of the OS.

-Olivier